# PGP keyserver for closed work group

Tags: permissions, pgp

I am looking for a PGP key server for our university work group. It is a closed work group so I do not need a public key server. Also I want to avoid to install and administrate our own server.

I found a lot of key servers. Alas they all seem to be completely public regarding key management.

I would like to use a server that provides administrative accounts and permissions. This means it should require an administrator to register to enable creation of closed key pools with exclusive control over adding and removing keys from those pools. It would be ok if the server is publicly accessible in the internet, only key management has to be restricted.

Is there a (free) key server service in the web that allows to create closed key pools?

Comment: Aside from service recommendations being explicitly offtopic here, I'm also not sure about what the point of restricting key management would be. Are you looking for this due to privacy / data protection reasons, or are you hoping to create "recipient groups" that would somehow propagate to each sender's address book? Your post sounds a bit like the latter, but it's not how PGP keyservers work at all...

Comment: Security reasons. There are servers that check for authenticity of added accounts. For large/global communities this may be ok. I want to go beyond that and restrict changes to a single person since this is safer and easier for a small group of people.

Comment: But doesn't PGP already have a mechanism for that? Instead of having users trust a specific server's contents, create a group-wide or university-wide PGP key that signs (certifies) member PGP keys, and have users trust that. (Essentially making a PGP CA.)

Comment: @user1686 Well, maybe that would an alternative. Depends from the effort and complexity. I have no idea how to do that. Do you have more information at hand?

Comment: I'm not sure such a service exists that's free. [Mailvelope](https://www.mailvelope.com/en/) seems to be designed for use by organizations, but it's not free, and I'm not entirely sure it actually does what you are looking for anyway. Your best option is probably just to bite the bullet and set up your own server, and then you can run a [Web Key Directory (WKD)](https://wiki.gnupg.org/WKD) on it, which one person can manage.